# Move window to other space by pushing; multiple monitors

Tags: display, spaces

as discussed [here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5542130?tstart=0) it is impossible to move a   window to another space by pushing it against the side of the screen. I wanted to know if there now is a workaround for this, since it is really annoying, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The workarounds are fairly well described on the page you linked...

- Disable 'Displays have separate Spaces' in System Preferences > Mission Control.
  This will re-enable the drag action, if you hit the extreme left or right of the screen pair.
- Grab the title bar & use the appropriate shortcut key  <kbd>Ctrl ⌃</kbd>    <kbd>[Number]</kbd>  - though this needs setting up in System Preferences > Keyboard > Mission Control. Commands are added with each Space, but not activated by default.
  You can also use  <kbd>Ctrl ⌃</kbd>   <kbd>←</kbd>  or  <kbd>Ctrl ⌃</kbd>   <kbd>→</kbd>

Comment: however 'Displays have separate Spaces' removes the ability to have full Screen on each monitor. And I'd rather just use the mouse and not the keyboard. so there apparently isn't an option. thanks anyways.

Comment: hmm... I guess. As someone who tends to 'drive' 2-handed - one on mouse one on keyboard, plus never use anything in fullscreen, I can see how our working methods/solutions may not suit each other :/